# Switch Statements with months

Tags: java, null, switch-statement

My assignment is to print formatted String Month # is NNNN (where the # sign is value of field `monthNumber` and NNNN is the value of field `monthName`. The problem is, when I click `getMonthName`, it comes out to 'null'.

How do I fix that?

```
public class Month {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int monthNumber;
    private String monthName;
    private String newMonthName;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Month
     */
    public Month(int input){ 
        if((input == 0) || (input > 12)){
            System.out.println("Error: Month number must be between 1 and 12");
        }
        else if(input < 0){
            System.out.println("Error: Month number must be positive");
        }
        else{ //the value of the input is valid
            System.out.println("Month number is VALID");
        }
        setMonthName(monthName);
        printMonth(input);
        monthNumber = input;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void setMonthName(String monthName)
    {
        switch(monthNumber){
            case 1:
                monthName = "January";
                break;
            case 2:
                monthName = "February";
                break;
            case 3:
                monthName = "March";
                break;
            case 4:
                monthName = "April";
                break;
            case 5:
                monthName = "May";
                break;
            case 6:
                monthName = "June";
                break;
            case 7:
                monthName = "July";
                break;
            case 8:
                monthName = "August";
                break;
            case 9:
                monthName = "September";
                break;
            case 10:
                monthName = "October";
                break;
            case 11:
                monthName = "November";
                break;
            case 12:
                monthName = "December";
                break;
            default:
                monthName = "Invalid month";
                break;
        } 
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void printMonth(int input)
    {
        switch(input){
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is not a month");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is January");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is February");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is March");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is April");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is May");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is June");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is July");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is August");
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is September");
                break;
            case 10:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is October");
                break;
            case 11:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is November");
                break;
            case 12:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + " is December");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Month " + input + "is an invalid month");
                break;
        }
    }       

    /**
     * 
     */
    public int getMonthNumber()
    {
        return monthNumber;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public String getMonthName()
    {
        return monthName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you seem to assign `monthNumber` only *after* calling `setMonthName()`.

Rearrange the code in your constructor:

```
   monthNumber = input;
   setMonthName();
   printMonth(input);
```

Also, in `setMonthName()`, you assign to the parameter, which due to having the same name overshadows the field in the class.  (It is a good idea to turn on the warning for that in your IDE) Remove the parameter from `setMonthName()`, then you will actually set the field in the object.

```
private void setMonthName()
{
    switch(monthNumber){
    [...]
    }
}
```

Finally, unrelated to the problem you asked, I recommend changing `printMonth(int input)` to use the fields in the object instead of duplicating your switch statement from `setMonthName()`.

Comment: Well, to correct myself in time, String is not quite a primitive type, but still immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1.

`monthName` in method `setMonthName()` is no the same thing as **field** `monthName` in class `Month`. When setting name in method, field is still null.

Problem 2.

`monthNumber` which is used is `setMonthName()` method is set after call to that method. `monthNumber` will be always **0** at this point and you'll always go to default clause in your switch.

Fix 1.

```
private void setMonthName(String monthName)
{
    switch(monthNumber){
        case 1:
            this.monthName = "January";
            break;
        case 2:
            this.monthName = "February";
            break;
      ...
```

Fix 2.

```
monthNumber = input;
setMonthName(monthName);
printMonth(input);
```

Summary.

Read about passing arguments in java. Changes mentioned above will fix your code, but won't fix your knowledge on java.

Comment: I do not want to downvote you but I seriously think your argument on "Problem 1" is invalid.

Comment: @Victor because, it's not an argument, it's a fact. Assuming that an answer has to provide working code without any educational addition is invalid. Hence summary directing for more lecture. I don't care as much about being voted as having feeling that I gave something to think of and push into right direction. Especially in questions covering basics of a language.

Comment: According to the official documentation,
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html
the use of `this` keyword is completely optional if the method arguments are not having the same names as the class properties.
That is, you can assign and access members from within the class without the `this` keyword at your sole discretion.

Comment: @Victor Yet still they are, method argument having the same name as class field. To make it short, there is just one correct answer to a question like this: "read the darn java tutorial before asking questions". Everything more than that is just a courteasy of mine (or anyone else). I fixed the code so now it has a chance to give reasonable results, pointed out what has to be done in the first place to understand what went wrong. Including more information would be pointless, and that's the end of story for me. Excuse me from rewriting tutorials/analyzing switch statements.